# Can I add an additional three way circuit to a three way circuit wired as diagram

Tags: electrical

Need some help if this scenario is possible. Can I add an additional independent three way circuit to an existing three way circuit wired as picture?

How will be the basic circuit layout to make it work using the same source of power, run an extra 14/4 wire to the second three way circuit? Or can I do it adding only 14/2 wire or wires?

Diagram:

[image]

Comment: It’s not clear.  What are you trying to do? Add addition switches to the same load/light?  Or duplicate the circuit to control a new load/light?

Comment: Currents must be equal in every cable, so you cannot run two parallel 14/2 cables if you need 4 conductors.   If you simply want to add a third control point for the same lamp, that's easy sauce - just put the new switch in the middle and wire a bone stock standard 3-switch 3/4 way setup.

Comment: If you're trying to add another light switch, it needs to be DPDT to switch the red and black. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_switching#More_than_two_locations

Comment: @DrMoishePippik a North American 4-way is not DPDT, true DPDT switches have 6 terminals, a 4-way switch only has 4 terminals and operates just a bit different than DPDT.

Comment: If you jumpered the 4 non-common contacts on a DPDT in an X, and then did not use the top row, you would have a 4-way.